# AppStore frozen on Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: catalina, mac-appstore

I just reformatted my SSD and reinstalled Catalina 10.15.7.  Everything appears to be fine, there are no updates available, but my AppStore is unresponsive.  It launches with a window, but the window remains black and the wait cursor appears.  My only option is to Force Quit.  How can I fix this issue?